# In Python, why zipped elements get separated, when added to a list?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, list, iterator

I wanted to create names like A1, B2, C3 and D4

```
batches = zip('ABCD', range(1, 5))

for i in batches:
  batch = i[0] + str(i[1])
  print(batch)
```

This produces the output as expected:

```
A1
B2
C3
D4
```

However, if I initialize a list batch_list as empty and add each batch to it, as follows:

```
batch_list = []

batches = zip('ABCD', range(1, 5))

for i in batches:
  batch_list += i[0] + str(i[1])

print(batch_list)
```

The output goes as:

```
['A', '1', 'B', '2', 'C', '3', 'D', '4']
```

Why not?

```
['A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'D4']
```

Comment: Your _extending_ the list not _appending_ to it.

Comment: The code becomes clearer and less confusing if you use `batch_list = [ch + str(n) for ch, n in zip('ABCD', range(1, 5))]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the `+=` operator you are appending each item in the string to your `batch_list`. So one way to avoid breaking the string is to wrap it in a list.

```
batch_list = []
for i in zip('ABCD', range(1,5)):
    batch_list += [i[0] + str(i[1])]
print(batch_list)
```

**output**

```
['A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'D4']
```

BTW, it's often better to use the `list.append` and `list.extend` methods than to use `+=`. Although code using `+=` is shorter, using the methods makes the code a little more readable, but there are other benefits as well, like the ability to mutate global lists, although some may argue that you shouldn't be doing that anyway. ;)

---

But there are better ways to write this.

You can use a list comprehension, and let the `.format` method combine the letter with the number, that way there's no need to explicitly call the `str` constructor.

```
batch_list = ['{}{}'.format(*u) for u in zip('ABCD', range(1, 5))]
```

Another option is to use `enumerate`, rather than zipping with a `range`. The `enumerate` function allows you to supply a starting number, rather than using the default starting number of zero.

```
batch_list = ['{}{}'.format(v, i) for i, v in enumerate('ABCD', 1)]
```

This is probably the most efficient way, unless you have Python 3.6, in which case you can use a f-string to do the formatting:

```
batch_list = [f'{v}{i}' for i, v in enumerate('ABCD', 1)]
```

Comment: Each of the answers I got from @Danil Speransky, Christian Dean and PM 2Ring is worth its weight in gold. I am voting yours (PM 2Ring) as the right answer for the wealth of info provided, besides the succinctly correct code provided. It is really sad and shameful that I cannot mark multiple responses as right answers.

Comment: @SeshadriR You can upvote as many answers as you wish, though.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, that's what I did to express my gratitude to others.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your extending the list rather than appending to it. Python considers strings sequences as well:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l += 'ab'
>>> l
['a', 'b']
```

Because of this, `+=` will extend the list by unpacking each item from the left hand iterable into the right hand list. Behind the scenes, `+=` is syntactic sugar for `list.__iadd__`:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.__iadd__('abc')
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

`list.__iadd__` when passed an iterable, has the same behavior as `list.extended`:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.extend('ab')
>>> l
['a', 'b']
```

To get desired behavior, use `list.append` instead:

```
batch_list.append(i[0] + str(i[1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Because it considers your string as an array.

```
>>> arr = []
>>> arr += 'str'
>>> arr
['s', 't', 'r']
```

Try this:

```
batch_list += [i[0] + str(i[1])]
```

Or this:

```
batch_list.append(i[0] + str(i[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> batch_list = []
>>> for i, v in zip('ABCD', count(1)): # count(1) -> start counter at 1
...     batch = '{}{}'.format(i, v)
...     batch_list.append(batch)
... 
>>> batch_list
['A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'D4']
```

Comment: While this produces the desired result, it doesn't answer the question why the second approach didn't work as expected.

Comment: @mkrieger1, Quite simply, because the answer has already been given. I suggest an alternative solution based on range parameter.